# zgeev not giving correct eigenvalue

Tags: fortran

```
subroutine Ceigen(n,Uf,Ud,d)
implicit none 
integer ::    n,info,i,j,lwork=-1
complex(8) ::    Ud(n,n),Uf(n,n),rwork(2*n),d(n)
complex(8),allocatable :: work(:)
complex(8),dimension(1,1) :: vr,vl
allocate(work(0:n-1))
Ud=Uf 
call zgeev('N','N', n, Ud, n, d, vl, 1, vr, 1, work, lwork, rwork, info)
lwork=work(1)
deallocate(work)
allocate(work(n))
call zgeev('N','N', n, Ud, n, d, vl, 1, vr, 1, work, lwork, rwork, info)

end subroutine Ceigen
```

I am using this subroutine to get the eigenvalues of a large complex matrix which is not symmetric.

However, every time I am getting the following error

> ** On entry to ZGEEV parameter number 12 had an illegal value Note: The following floating-point exceptions are signalling:
>   IEEE_UNDERFLOW_FLAG IEEE_DENORMAL

`lwork` is the 12th parameter. However if I don't assign `lwork =work(1)` I am getting every eigenvalue zero.
Can anyone help?

Comment: Try `lwork = max(1,n)` as stated in the documentation.

Comment: Do you call `Ceigen` more than once?

Comment: Do not use complex(8). Not only it us ugly and non-portable. It is also confusing, because it is not compatible with complex*8.

Comment: If I use the same code but change complex(8) to complex(16) it doesn't work. It says lwork has illegal value. Why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By assigning a value to `lwork` during its declaration, you implicitly give it the `save` attribute:

```
integer ::    n,info,i,j,lwork=-1
```

That means, that it will keep its value between function calls. In case you call `Ceigen` a second time, it will not be `-1` for the first call, but potentially an illegal value (`lwork < 2*n`, see the [source code](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-3.1.1-html/zgeev.f.html)).

On the other hand, if you don't change `lwork`, it will stay `-1`, and you will always query the work array size and never do any calculation.

As a remedy, separate the declaration and the assignment:

```
integer ::    n,info,i,j,lwork
!...
lwork=-1
```